# Identify an Iron Man animated TV episode in which Iron Man recharged his armor using a Walkman

Tags: story-identification, marvel, tv, episode-identification, iron-man

I remember watching an Iron Man cartoon on TV. I don't know the name of the original TV series because I watched it on a TV show called *Fox Kids*, which used to show different cartoons each day without disclosing its name. The TV show was probably a partnership between TV channels viz. Fox Kids (US) and Star Plus (India).

MODOK and the Mandarin were villains. The Mandarin had real magical powers of rings unlike in *Iron Man 3*. War Machine was also in it. In the intro, Tony used to put on the helmet using an electromagnetic/invisible force, not like [this](https://youtu.be/k4UlEcjLOiw) (but, it can be intro of different season, not necessarily different TV series).

Now, about the episode I am looking for:

- Pepper was kidnapped or lost.
- Iron Man found her, but he went out of power.
- The scene: It was a vertical tunnel. Underground.
- Pepper had a Walkman with her.
- Iron Man connected a wire coming out of his finger to the Walkman and told Pepper to play it on high volume.
- And, it worked.

There can be a little bit of variation because the images in my memory aren't 100% clear. Can you please identify the episode?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the description it should be ***Iron Man: The Animated Series*** Episode 1x04 - **Silence My Companion, Death My Destination**, there are however some minor differences.

While Iron Man uses his "fingercable" to recharge, the kidnapped person isn't Pepper Potts, but Spider-Woman (=Julia Carpenter)'s daughter *Rachel Carpenter*.

The relevant scene can be found here: